# how to add conditional join in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, api

I want to add 2 different joins in linq based on the parameter i am passing .
Say "isHub" is the parameter .
If isHub = true : I want to return list of cities
If isHub = false: I want to return list of countries

This is my current Query

```
   public List<ControlTowerCity> GetControlTowerMapData(bool IsHub)
    {
        using (var context = new LadingControlTowerEntities())
        {
            var mapcityDetail =
            (from SLD in context.ShipmentLocations 
             join CMD in context.CityMasters on SLD.City equals CMD.ID

             select new ControlTowerCity
             { 
                 Name = CMD.Name,

             }).ToList();
            return mapcityDetail;
        }
    }
```

Here is want to add join somthing like this

```
if(ishHub == true){
  join CMD in context.CityMasters on SLD.City equals CMD.ID
} 
else {
 join CMD in context.CountryMasters on SLD.Country equals CMD.ID
}
```

Any Help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Maybe `join CMD in (ishHub ? context.CityMasters : context.CountryMasters) on SLD.City equals CMD.ID` but I'm unsure whether it will compile or not. Could you try it and tell?

Comment: @Rafalon  I tried this, no joy

Comment: Yes, I expected this. I think it could only work if `context.CityMasters` was of same type as `context.CountryMasters`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using (var context = new LadingControlTowerEntities()) {
    var query = context.ShipmentLocations.AsQueryable();
    // if you have any condition (for example, what you said in comment):
    query = query.Where(t => t.Status == "A");
    IQueryable<ControlTowerCity> resultQuery;
    if (ishHub)
        resultQuery = query.Join(context.CityMasters, t => t.City, t => t.ID, (o, i) => new ControlTowerCity { Name = i.Name });
    else
        resultQuery = query.Join(context.CountryMasters, t => t.Country, t => t.ID, (o, i) => new ControlTowerCity { Name = i.Name });
    var mapcityDetail = resultQuery.ToList();
    return mapcityDetail;
}
```

Comment: thanks @javad amiry,  how to apply filters in this query ?
In this case i need to apply a where condition 
_where shipmentlocations.Status = "A"_

Comment: What I have done in your answer is something like this 

_var query = context.ShipmentLocations .AsQueryable();
.Where(x => x.Status == "A");_

Is this right ?

Comment: @ChetanBirajdar Yes you did right. Ill edit the answer and add condition sample

Answer (score 2):

For this task it is easier to use the [method based syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/method-based-query-syntax-examples-join-linq-to-dataset) to concatenate your `IQueryable`s instead of using the query syntax (see for example javad amiry's answer) to avoid the overhead of additional `from` and `select` statements.

But to answer your question: With the query syntax, you would need to store your `IQueryable` in an extra variable and use this in the `in` part of your `from` above your joins again.

```
var query = (
    from SLD in Context.ShipmentLocations
    where ... // you could add some filters here
    select SLD
);

IQueryable<ControlTowerCity> query2;
if(ishHub == true)
{
    query2 = (
        from SLD in query 
        join CMD in context.CityMasters on SLD.City equals CMD.ID
        select CMD
    )
} 
else {
    query2 = (
        from SLD in query 
        join CMD in context.CountryMasters on SLD.Country equals CMD.ID
        select CMD
    )
}

var result = (
    from CMD in query2
    select new ControlTowerCity
    { 
        Name = CMD.Name,
    }
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you have a `if..else` branch like

```
   public List<ControlTowerCity> GetControlTowerMapData(bool IsHub)
    {
       if(isHub)
       {
        using (var context = new LadingControlTowerEntities())
        {
            var mapcityDetail =
            (from SLD in context.ShipmentLocations 
             join CMD in context.CityMasters on SLD.City equals CMD.ID

             select new ControlTowerCity
             { 
                 Name = CMD.Name,

             }).ToList();
            return mapcityDetail;
        }
      }
     else
      {
         // other part of query with different join
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to create a generic extension function of `IQueryable`. This way you can use it for every problem where you have to select either A or B depending on some input variable.

See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

The extension function I'll create is similar to a standard [IQueryable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.join?view=netframework-4.7.2).

The difference is that it has an extra input Boolean parameter and instead of one `outerKeySelector`, it has two `outerKeySelectors`: `outerKeySelectorTrue` and `outerKeySelectorFalse`.

If the Boolean parameter is true, we'll use `outerKeySelectorTrue` to join, else we'll use `outerkeySelectorFalse` to join

```
IQueryable<TResult> Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TOuter> outer,
    IQueryable<TInner> inner,

    // the boolean to decide which OuterKeySelector to use
    bool isHub,

    // the two KeySelectors: one for true and one for false
    Expression<Func<TOuter,TKey>> outerKeySelectorTrue, 
    Expression<Func<TOuter,TKey>> outerKeySelectorFalse,

    // the rest is standard IQueryable.Join
    Expression<Funt<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector
    Expression<Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>> resultSelector);
{
    return outer.Join(inner,
        // decide which outerKeySelector to use:
        isHub ? outerKeySelectorTrue : outerKeySelectorFalse, 

        // the rest is as in a standard join:
        innerKeySelector,
        resultSelector);
}
```

That's all! All we needed was a function declaration similar to already existing join, and one statement that calls this already existing join using either outerKeySelectorTrue, or outerKeySelectorFalse

### Usage

#### Standard join

```
var result = dbContext.ShipmentLocations         // join ShipmentLocations
    .Join(dbContext.CityMasters,                 // with CityMasters
    shipmentLocation => shipmentLocation.CityId, // from ShipmentLocation take foreign key CityId
    cityMaster => cityMaster.Id,                 // from CityMaster take the primary key Id
    (shipmentLocation, cityMaster) => new        // when they match, make one new object
    {
        // select only the properties you plan to use
        Name = shipmentLocation.Name,
        Location = cityMaster.City,
        ...
    });
```

#### Extended join

Instead of one `outerKeySelector` we have two `outerKeySelectors`, the rest is equal to a standard join

```
bool isHub = ...
var result = dbContext.ShipmentLocations         // join ShipmentLocations
    .Join(dbContext.CityMasters,                 // with CityMasters

    // the boolean that decides which of the two outerKeySelectors to use
    isHub,                                       

    // the two outerKeySelectors: one for isHub true and one for isHub fale
    shipmentLocation => shipmentLocation.City,
    shipmentLocation => shipmentLocation.Country,

    // the innerKeySelector: used to compare with the selected outerKey
    cityMaster => cityMaster.Id,

    (shipmentLocation, cityMaster) => new        // when they match, make one new object
    {
        // select only the properties you plan to use
        ...
    });
```

The nice thing, is that this works with all IQueryables, whether they are ShipmentLocations and CityMasters, or Schools with Students, Clients with Orders, etc.

Besides, it is very similar to how LINQ is used, and it is only one statement